# How to share py2app file via email or anything

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, software-distribution, py2app

I have recently made a simple Hangman game and converted it into a .app file using Py2App. However, when I tried to send the folder(after zipping) to my friend via email, there is no actual application in the receiver's file.
Can you guys please help me how can I share .app file from py2app via email or is there anything or any platform through which I can share my file?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please remove the `tkinter` and `tk` tags? They don't seem related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you use gmail, try to upload the .app file or the zip file on your google drive cloud and share the link to your friend. go to the shared link and download your file! if you don't know how to do this check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77CmlRucp-Q

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this way out.